# Why is Jquery not finding my json_encoded() nested array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my PHP and Jquery: https://pastebin.com/ZCay6A55

Issue is that my Jquery is expecting a JSON result from PHP. In the PHP, I have created a nested array, which is then used by json_encode(). Issue is that when the result is alerted, I get no result.

If I modify Jquery such that I comment out dataType:"JSON", I am able to get a successful alert with the correct data (though I am not sure the format is correct).

So my PHP is attempting to create a JSON array of a nested array, but if Jquery is set to expect a JSON array, it doesn't seem to find the result. If Jquery is not set to expect a JSON array (AKA if I remove data:"JSON"), it finds the result. I think it's my PHP that's somehow not encoding my nested array into JSON properly...

```
$i=0; //array index
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findservice)) {
        $resultarray[$i] = array(
            'bn' => $row['bn'],
            'bd' => $row['bd']
        );
        $i++;
    }
    $jsonarray = json_encode($resultarray);
    echo $jsonarray;

----------------------------
$.post({
    url:"/search.php",
    processData:false,  //do not convert form to string
    contentType:false,  //FormData is designed to send only by multipart/form-data
    //dataType: "JSON",    //I get a result if this line is commented out. if not commented, I get no alert.
    data:form,
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try with String . I think you need to parse the data which you receive from server

Comment: try `var_dump($jsonarray)`, post the result in your question

Comment: from the *dataType* section in [this link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): *...If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response* ... *The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)...* Looks like there is indeed something wrong with the formatting of your php return variable.

Comment: var_dump($jsonarray) result:
```string(44) "[{"bn":"222222","bd":"d222222222eeeeeeeee"}]"```

I only have one row of data, and the data is correct, but I don't know if this is the correct format.

Comment: I have tried JSON.parse as well, no success